AnimatedVisibility fadeIn animations do not work for recomposed items but only for items enter composition?
I'm filtering items based on user selection and animating them back in a FlowRow that also inside a LazyColumn with keys are unique, however Compose does not remove items from composition, which is also what i need for scroll to not jump, but items that are in composition from previous filter do not have fadeIn animations. Other animations like shrink/expand/slide work fine.
In gif at first filtering item1 and second filtering item3 does not animate fadeIn

This is the ViewModel and filtering, most code is omitted
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val list = listOf(
        SomeData(id = "1", value = "Row1"),
        SomeData(id = "2", value = "Row2"),
        SomeData(id = "3", value = "Row3"),
        SomeData(id = "4", value = "Row4"),
        SomeData(id = "5", value = "Row5")
    )

    var itemList by mutableStateOf(list)

    var filter: Int = 0

    fun filter() {
        if (filter % 3 == 0) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[0],
                list[1],
                list[2]
            )
        } else if (filter % 3 == 1) {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[1],
                list[2]
            )
        } else {
            itemList = listOf(
                list[0],
                list[2],
                list[3]
            )
        }

        filter++
    }
}

data class SomeData(val id: String, val value: String)

Composable that contains items and animates after filtering takes effect.
@Composable
private fun StaggeredList(
    filter: String,
    itemList: List<SomeData>,
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {

        val itemWidth = (maxWidth - 8.dp) / 2

        FlowRow(
            modifier = Modifier,
            maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            itemList.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
                key(it.id) {

                    var visible by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(false)
                    }

                    LaunchedEffect(filter) {
                        visible = false
                        delay(2000)
                        visible = true
                    }

                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        visible = visible,
                        enter = fadeIn(tween(2000)),
                        exit = fadeOut(tween(2000))
                    ) {
                        MyRow(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(itemWidth, 200.dp),
                            item = it
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Rest of the code to reproduce the issue
@Preview
@Composable
private fun FlowRowCompositionPreview() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<SomeViewModel>()
    MyComposable(viewModel)
}

@Composable
fun MyComposable(someViewModel: SomeViewModel) {

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(backgroundColor)) {

        val itemList = someViewModel.itemList

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
        ) {

            items(5) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                        .fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp)
                )
            }

            item {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = {
                        someViewModel.filter()
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Filter")
                }
            }
            item {
                StaggeredList(
                    filter = someViewModel.filter.toString(),
                    itemList = itemList
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


Make enter and exit animations little shorter than delay in LaunchedEffect.
When visibility changes before previous animation has ended, AnimatedVisibility stops the animation and content changes visibility instantly according to the new state. So when you set visible = true just before exit animation has ended, animation is stopped and items appear without enter animation.
Edit:
Correction - as @Thracian noted in comments, when interrupted, the other animation still plays, but very quickly. The speed of that animation is independent from the stage of the interrupted animation.

AnimatedVisibility uses Transition interanlly. In Transition.kt I found this piece of code:
private fun updateAnimation(
    initialValue: T = value,
    isInterrupted: Boolean = false,
) {
    if (initialValueAnimation?.targetValue == targetValue) {
        // This animation didn't change the target value, so let the initial value animation
        // take care of it.
        animation = TargetBasedAnimation(
            interruptionSpec,
            typeConverter,
            initialValue,
            initialValue,
            velocityVector.newInstance() // 0 velocity
        )
        useOnlyInitialValue = true
        durationNanos = animation.durationNanos
        return
    }
    val specWithoutDelay =
        if (isInterrupted && !isSeeking) {
            // When interrupted, use the default spring, unless the spec is also a spring.
            if (animationSpec is SpringSpec<*>) animationSpec else interruptionSpec
        } else {
            animationSpec
        }

Which implies that the interruption animation spec is interruptionSpec, which defined as:
interruptionSpec = spring(visibilityThreshold = visibilityThreshold)


You are right, the reason AnimatedVisibility  stops the animation but after checking again they appear with enter animation. Checked out again with slideIn/Out animation. They actually play faster, don't know with what easing though. The reason i set same delay is i want exit transition to be in composition because items are in a Composable that also inside a LazyColumn. And exit animation finishes early when they enter composition they appear below visible section. This answer is acceptable in cases that happens when there is no parent Composable available

However, i made a different decision choice changing keys to be unique for filtering as well so each of the items exit compostion when filtering is done, and store last FlowRow height and when item enter composition they still appear on screen because i assigned this height as min to show at least some of the items in worst case

You are right, animation still plays. It looks like the animation spec used for interruption is a default spring. I've updated the answer @Thracian

It's interesting that it picks a spring animation. In such a case Animatables run with same easing but from interrupted value. This answer requires setting height for my case inside a scrolalble  or manually scrolling for animation to be shown and cases where items leave composition not animating naturally but very well and explaining reason and how to run enter animations. Best approach i still think is implementing 2 maps and compare data like combination of AnimatedVisibility/Content and Modifier.animate() to have enter exit animations work properly in every case.

But it's a lot of work. If specifications allow use LazyLists for such position change animations to be executed properly.

As suggested in Jan Itor's answer setting delay time a bit longer than exit animation lets enter animations run with specified easing. Otherwise enter animations still run but faster as in gif below.

With this snippet
@Composable
private fun StaggeredList(
    filter: String,
    itemList: List<SomeData>,
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {

        val itemWidth = (maxWidth - 8.dp) / 2

        val heightList by remember {
            mutableStateOf(
                List(10) { index ->
                    if (index == 0) {
                        200.dp
                    } else Random.nextInt(120, 200).dp
                }
            )
        }

        FlowRow(
            modifier = Modifier,
            maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            itemList.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
                key(it.id) {

                    var visible by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(false)
                    }

                    LaunchedEffect(filter) {
                        visible = false
                        delay(1500)
                        visible = true
                    }

                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        visible = visible,
                        enter = fadeIn(tween(1500)) +
                                slideInVertically(tween(1500)) {
                                    it / 2
                                },
                        exit = fadeOut(tween(1500))
                                + slideOutVertically(tween(1500)) {
                            it / 2
                        }
                    ) {
                        MyRow(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(itemWidth, heightList[index]),
                            item = it
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But setting a delay longer in composable causes scrollable LazyColumn to be resized and items to be displayed below. To solve this i retrieved FlowRow height before and set it as height. Also i decided using keys that not only unique to data but also to filtering as well with  key(it.id + filter)
@Composable
private fun StaggeredList(
    filter: String,
    itemList: List<SomeData>,
) {
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {

        val itemWidth = (maxWidth - 8.dp) / 2

        val heightList by remember {
            mutableStateOf(
                List(10) { index ->
                    if (index == 0) {
                        200.dp
                    } else Random.nextInt(120, 200).dp
                }
            )
        }

        var height by remember {
            mutableStateOf(0.dp)
        }

        val density = LocalDensity.current

        FlowRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    val newHeight = it.size.height
                    if (newHeight != 0) {
                        height = with(density) {
                            newHeight.toDp()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .heightIn(min = height)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Green),
            maxItemsInEachRow = 2,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            itemList.forEachIndexed { index, it ->

                //  These keys are unique for items for every filtering
                // without filter if items exist from previous filtering
                // they don't leave recomposition
                key(it.id + filter) {

                    var visible by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(false)
                    }

                    LaunchedEffect(filter) {
                        visible = false
                        delay(250)
                        visible = true
                        height = 0.dp
                    }

                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        visible = visible,
                        enter = fadeIn(tween(250)) +
                                slideInVertically(tween(250)) {
                                    it / 2
                                },
                        exit = fadeOut(tween(250)) + slideOutVertically(tween(250)) {
                            it / 2
                        }
                    ) {
                        MyRow(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(itemWidth, heightList[index]),
                            item = it
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In this case by removing items from composition with filter unique keys i also forfeited all of the exit animations instead of in other case only items that are recomposed having exit animations while items that don't exist in new filter were removed.


I think best approach is neither of these answers but comparing previous and current list, animating item positions if they exist in previous and current lists or Compositions and animate new items(entered composition) with fadeIn as Modifier.animateItem() does but it requires more work.
